# Mass balance for gas in a fixed volume

Tags: mass, conservation-laws, physical-chemistry, ideal-gas

I am trying to generate an equation that describes the mass balance of a gas in a fixed volume. The application is simulating the sweep out time of the cell in a laser-based instrument which measures the concentration of the gas.

I think this should be something like:
$$dC/dt = F*Cin - F*C + C$$

where $C$ is the mole fraction of the gas in the cell, Cin is the mole fraction of the gas coming in, F is the flow, which is held constant along with the pressure.

but I don't think it's fully correct. My question: what is the equation which would describe this process?

Comment: What you are seeking called coninuity equation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation